# How to delete rows from two tables which are in common with single query in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I have two tables t1 and t2

table t1 as follows:

```
id   name
1     x
2     y
3     z
```

table t2 as follows:

```
id      name
1         a
121       b
131       c
```

Here I am selecting rows that are common in both the tables i.e.,

```
SELECT * 
from t1,t2 
where t1.id=t2.id;
```

Now I want to delete the rows when id=1 in both the tables at once. I have tried to delete the rows but I am able to delete only in one table but not both. Can anyone help me out in solving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with a [data modifying common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
with common_ids as (
   select id 
   from t1
   intersect
   select id 
   from t2
), t1_delete as (
   delete from t1
   where id in (select id from common_ids)
)
delete from t2
where id in (select id from common_ids);
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/NAQ26877